# Attachments do not display (Blank frame) with "IIf" statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to make a conditional display depending on a boolean value. (If true => display attachment, else display default img/nothing.)

The two tables :

```
T1(long T1_ID, txt firstname, attachment visa)
T2(long T2_ID, long fk_T1_ID, bool isValid)
```

So I used IIf statement :

```
SELECT T1.firstname, IIf(T2.isValid,T1.visa.FileData,Null) AS validSignature
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON...
```

Then I put `validSignature` as my source control into an attachment controller but it never displays anything...

When I display `.FileName` instead of `.FileData` into a textfield it works properly : it displays the right filename only when `isValid = TRUE`. But I NEED to display the picture itself, not only filename.

I have no idea of what I did wrong, so I am asking for your help.

Thank you

Comment: Try it the other way around. Take the `IIf(T2.isValid,T1.visa.FileData,Null)` statement in your query and remove it, just select `T1.visa.FileData`. The in the attachment control source put your `=IIf(T2.isValid,T1.visa.FileData,Null) `

Comment: I just tried it, exactly same problem. Display default image even when attachment is not empty ( = I got right `FileName`, but `FileData` wont display). I have no clue of what is happening.

Comment: Have you tried just using `T1.visa` ? That's what you would use when using T1 directly as source, I guess.

Comment: Also tried, and I got an error about multiple fields. If I cant manage to do that I will be forced to store many times in my Table the same picture and I think it mights slow the database a lot for nothing. If I do so, `T2.isValid` just have to be replaced by an attachment field.

Comment: Even when I do `IIf(T2.isValid,T1.visa.FileData, T1.visa.FileData)` it does not show anything, I think `IIf` just do not work with Attachment fields :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than bogging your database down with attachments, why not store the pictures in a folder and make the t1.visa field store the filename.

Then just set the `imagecontrol.picture = t1.visa`

I did this with an inventory database. The user clicks a button to open a filepicker to select photos to associate with each inventory item, and move them to a folder.  I used a separate images table and put and image control on my form with buttons that will allow them to flip through available photos for each item as well as change which photo is loaded as default. I can share the code if that is along the lines of what you want to do.

Comment: That is the kind of thing I want to do. But additionally I want to make the display of those pictures **CONDITIONAL**, depending on a boolean value which is stored into a table. I want to display no picture or a default picture into my controller if `FALSE` and the visa `FileData` if `TRUE`

Comment: Rather than using the recordset, use the `form_current` event procedure

Comment: Control source not "recordset" sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the syntax...i'm  on my phone, but like I said I would use an event procedure rather than iif statement in the control source.

```
Private sub your form_current() 
If me.isvalid = true then  
Me.imagecontrol.picture = me.visa 
Else  
Me.imagecontrol.picture = "default image path"  
End if  
End sub
```

Comment: thanks, exactly what I need. I will check that way tomorrow. I hope it will work, I forgot to tell you that I am working on a Continuous Form.